# how display sql query results using tbgridview in yii

Tags: php, sql, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I want to display this sql query using tbgridview in yii.

this is my controller.

```
public function actionSVI(){
    $list = Workstation::model()->listSvi();
    $this->render('svi',array(
        'list'=>$list,
    ));
}
```

my model and sql query.

```
public function listSvi(){
    $svi = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                ->select('*')
                ->from('workstation')
                ->where('ws_company_id=:id',array(':id'=>1))
                ->queryAll();

    return $svi;;
}
```

I'm currently displaying my query using this code.

```
<?php 
foreach($list as $each){
    $company = Workstation::model()->findByPK($each['ws_id']);
    echo  "<tr><td>" . $company->companyName ."</td><td>". CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($company->ws_id), array('view','id'=>$company->ws_id))."</td><td>" .$company->branchName ."</td>","<td>". $company->departmentName. "</tr></td>";
    }
```

?>

i just want to display it using this tbgridview.

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
'type'=>'striped',
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
'template'=>"{items}",
'columns'=>array(
            'companyName',
        'branchName',
        'departmentName',
        'ws_id',
    array(
        'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
        'template'=>'{view}',
        'buttons'=>array(
                'view'=>array('icon'=>'icon-search'),
            ),
    ),
),
)); ?>
<?php $this->endWidget();?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the easiest way to do what I think you want to do is by creating a [`CActiveDataProvider`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider) and use *that* as dataProvider for your widget. Also, if `Workstation` is an Active Record, you can do this:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria(
    array(
        'condition'=>"ws_company_id = '1'"
));

$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Workstation',array('criteria'=>$criteria));
```

Or something like that.

And then send that object to your view.

Answer (score 0):

If you use your own data from SQL query, try [CSqlDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSqlDataProvider)

```
$count=Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_user')->queryScalar();
$sql='SELECT * FROM tbl_user';
$dataProvider=new CSqlDataProvider($sql, array(
    'totalItemCount'=>$count,
    'sort'=>array(
        'attributes'=>array(
             'id', 'username', 'email',
        ),
    ),
    'pagination'=>array(
        'pageSize'=>10,
    ),
));
// $dataProvider->getData() will return a list of arrays.
```